# Why IPython shell can find urllib.parse while plain python shell can't?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble understanding the following behavior using Python 3.4.3:

```
In [1]: import urllib

In [3]: urllib.parse
Out[3]: <module 'urllib.parse' from '/home/laurent/anaconda/envs/springleaf/lib/python3.4/urllib/parse.py'>

In [4]: urllib.request
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-615cd424e6d8> in <module>()
----> 1 urllib.request

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
```

I looked at the urllib package in `[myenv]/lib/python3.4/urllib` but it just has an empty `__init__.py` and I can't figure out why the `parse` submodule would be visible while the `request` or `error` submodule are not.
The behavior I was expecting was to have all the modules visible.

**What is causing the `parse` module to be visible while the other modules are not?**

I can use `from urllib import request` just fine, but I'd like to understand the cause of the behavior.

**EDIT:**
As recommended in the comments, I ran the same commands in a plain python shell (I was using IPython 4.0.0 above):

```
>>> import urllib                                                                                         
>>> urllib.parse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parse'
>>> urllib.request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
```

The behavior is indeed different. It makes more sense to me as all submodules show the same behavior.

I would love it if someone could explain where the IPython specific behavior comes from ;).

Comment: BTW: Try do them in Python Shell, not IPython.

Comment: What does `print(urllib .__file__)` output?

Comment: @excaza My mistake - I read part of the question and answers but didn't catch it was also about ipython.